# Showing that the diagonal of $G \times G$ is maximal, where $G$ is simple

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have been trying to prove the following:

Let $G$ be simple, and write $\Gamma=G \times G$.  Let $D \le \Gamma$ be the diagonal subgroup, which consists of all elements of the form $(x,x)$, where $x \in G$.  Show that $D$ is a maximal subgroup of $\Gamma$.

As a hint I am given: Write $\Gamma=A \dot{\times} B$, where $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic to $G$ ($\dot{\times}$ denoting the internal direct product).  Show that $AD=\Gamma=BD$.  If $D \le H \le \Gamma$, show that $H \cap B \triangleleft \Gamma$, and thus $H \cap B \triangleleft B$.

I showed the first part of the hint easily, but now I'm stuck on showing that $H \cap B \triangleleft \Gamma$.  How can we characterize this subgroup?  I know it's a subset of $\bar{B}=\{(1,g)\,|\,g \in G\}$ and so it intersects the diagonal trivially.  That's all I have been able to say about it though.

How can I characterize $H \cap B$ in a way that will help show its normality in $\Gamma$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your notaion,  we get $\Gamma=AB=AD$. Hence $H=H \cap \Gamma=H\cap AD=(H \cap A)D$. Similarly, $H=(H\cap B)D$. Since $A\lhd \Gamma$, we get $H \cap A \lhd H$. Then $(H\cap A)B \lhd HB=\Gamma$. Now $H\cap A\cong (H \cap A)B/B \lhd \Gamma/B \cong A$. Since $A$ is simple, we get $H \cap A=1$ or $A$. Hence we get $H=D$ or $BD=\Gamma$, and we get $D$ is maximal.

I dont understand your hint. I think it should be $(\Gamma \cap B)A \lhd \Gamma$, not $\Gamma \cap B \lhd \Gamma$.