# The Diagonal Subgroup of $A \times A$ is Maximal iff $A$ is Simple

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, simple-groups

> Let $A$ be a group and $G = A \times A$. Define $D= \{(a,a)\mid a \in A\}$ (*the diagonal subgroup of* $G$). Prove that $D$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$ if and only if $A$ is *simple*, i.e. it has no proper normal subgroup.

I saw a similar version to this question on StackExchange but I didn't quite understand the solution which showed only one direction. I'm hoping to see a solution for both directions.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the "similar" question you speak of?

Comment: Sure.
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/673290/showing-that-the-diagonal-of-g-times-g-is-maximal-where-g-is-simple

Comment: If $A$ is not simple and has proper nontrivial normal subgroup $N$, then $D < (N\times N)D < G$, so $D$ is not maximal.

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake. Thank you. Do you have a solution for the converse?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The result follows easily from the following theorem.

**Theorem** If $D \leq H \leq G$ then there exists a normal subgroup $N$ of $A$ such that $H = \{(a,b) \in G \mid ab^{-1} \in N\}$.

**Proof**

Let $N = \{a \in A \mid (a,1) \in H\}$. Clearly $N$ is a subgroup of $A$.

If $(a,1) \in H$ and $b \in A$ then $(bab^{-1},1) = (b,b)(a,1)(b^{-1},b^{-1}) \in H$ since $D \leq H$. Hence $N$ is a normal subgroup of $A$.

For all $a,b \in A$, we have $(ab^{-1}, 1)(b,b) =(a,b)$, so $(a,b) \in H$ iff $(ab^{-1}, 1) \in H$ iff $ab^{-1} \in N$. $\square$

**Edit** I suppose for completeness one should show that $\{(a,b) \in G \mid ab^{-1} \in N\}$ is a subgroup of $G$ whenever $N$ is a normal subgroup of $A$ which follows from the identity
$$a_1a_2^{-1}(b_1b_2^{-1})^{-1} = (a_1b_1^{-1})b_1b_2^{-1}(a_2b_2^{-1})^{-1}b_2b_1^{-1},$$ 
and hence there is a one-to-one correspondence between normal subgroups of $A$ and subgroups of $G$ containing $D$.